# Error Inserting into multiple tables SQLite Android

Tags: android, insert, android-sqlite

I have a very straight error. In my SQLiteHelper I create 2 tables:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.letscook.thanhta.letscook.R;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CookBook.db";

protected static final String RECIPE_CATEGORY = "RECIPE_CATEGORY";
protected static final String INGREDIENT_TYPE = "INGREDIENT_TYPE";

public static final String CREATE_RECIPE_CATEGORY = "create table if not exists "
        + RECIPE_CATEGORY +
        "(Recipe_Category_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        "Recipe_Category_name TEXT, " +
        "Description TEXT);";
public static final String CREATE_INGREDIENT_TYPE= "create table if not exists " +
        INGREDIENT_TYPE +
        "(Ingredient_type_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +
        "Ingredient_type_name TEXT);";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RECIPE_CATEGORY);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_INGREDIENT_TYPE);
        db.close();}
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)     {        
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + RECIPE_CATEGORY);
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + INGREDIENT_TYPE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

In MainActivity i insert into those 2 tables

```
    public class DataBaseInsertActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ContentValues  values = new ContentValues();
    private void Insert(ContentValues values, String table) {
        db.insert(table,null,values);
    }

    public void doInsertRECIPE_CATEGORY(int id, String name, String    description){
    values.put("Recipe_Category_id", id);
    values.put("Recipe_Category_name",name);
    values.put("Description", description);
    Insert(values, "RECIPE_CATEGORY");
    }

    public  void doInsertINGREDIENT_TYPE(int id, String name){
    values.put("Ingredient_type_id",id);
    values.put("Ingredient_type_name",name);
    Insert(values, "INGREDIENT_TYPE");
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_base);
        //CREATE database
        SQLiteHelper helper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
      }
```

> ```
>     doInsertRECIPE_CATEGORY(0, "All", "All recipes");
>     doInsertRECIPE_CATEGORY(1, "Snack", "Fast and fun!");
>     doInsertINGREDIENT_TYPE(0, "meat");
>     doInsertINGREDIENT_TYPE(1, "fish");
> }}
> ```

ERROR:

```
09-09 18:50:58.494  12358-12358/com.letscook.thanhta.letscook E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "Recipe_id": syntax error
09-09 18:50:58.518  12358-12358/com.letscook.thanhta.letscook E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: INGREDIENT_TYPE
09-09 18:50:58.518  12358-12358/com.letscook.thanhta.letscook E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting Ingredient_type_name=meat Description=Fast and fun! Ingredient_type_id=0 Recipe_Category_name=Snack Recipe_Category_id=1
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: INGREDIENT_TYPE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO INGREDIENT_TYPE(Ingredient_type_name,Description,Ingredient_type_id,Recipe_Category_name,Recipe_Category_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

I don't know why "Recipe_Category_name" and "Recipe_Category_id" are still in Insert when insert to second table.

Comment: Have you considered using a library like ActiveAndroid for this db needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!
It's cause error because in class `DataBaseInsertActivity`

```
ContentValues  values = new ContentValues();
```

has been put in `onCreate` , it should be put into seperate class like this:

```
public void doInsertRECIPE_CATEGORY(int id, String name, String        description)   {
ContentValues  values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Recipe_Category_id", id);
values.put("Recipe_Category_name",name);
values.put("Description", description);
Insert(values, "RECIPE_CATEGORY");
}
public  void doInsertINGREDIENT_TYPE(int id, String name){
ContentValues  values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Ingredient_type_id",id);
values.put("Ingredient_type_name",name);
Insert(values, "INGREDIENT_TYPE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not call `getWritableDatabase()` in `SQLiteDatabaseHelper` `onCreate()`. That will fail with a "called recursively" exception.

While there, remove the `close()` and the `try`-`catch`. If there's a problem, it needs to be thrown and not ignored.

Uninstall and reinstall your app to trigger `onCreate()` to be called again.